# Unable to manipulate the data using ngFor directive

Tags: angular

this is my ts file .

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: "my-app",
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']

})
export class AppComponent  {
    employees: [
        { name: "ABC", position: "Programmer" },
        { name: "CDF", position: "HR" }
    ];
}
```

here it is my html file

```
<h3>List Of Records </h3>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let emp of  employees ">
            <td>{{emp.name}}</td>
            <td>{{emp.position}}</td>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" id="edit" value="Edit">
                <input type="submit" id="delete" value="Delete">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I dont know why i am unable to  get those two properties in my table . and also i am unable to get both edit and delete buttons .
but when i remove ngFOr directive than i am able to see those two buttons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct is

```
employees = [
  { name: "ABC", position: "Programmer" },
  { name: "CDF", position: "HR" }
];
```

You are using ':' which means you are defining the type of the 'employees' property. You have to use the '=' operator to set its value.

Comment: aah! those little mistakes ruined my day . well thankyou and yeah i got the point

Comment: You're welcome. I made the same mistake some times too ;)

Answer (score 1):

you can use ":" this is the correct syntax

```
  employees:Array<object> = [
    { name: "ABC", position: "Programmer" },
    { name: "CDF", position: "HR" }
  ];
```